# Сократить потребление ресурсов Selenium + Google Chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте!
Есть некоторый скрипт с использованием Selenium, на драйвере Chrome, который нужно выполнить одновременно несколько (от 10) раз на одной машине. Запуск скрипта производится с одной машины через Paramiko на другой. Chrome ест много, и при одновременном выполнении скрипта от уже 3 раз начинает сильно затягивать время выполнения (оно особенно важно).

Есть ли какие-то методы решения проблемы? Как сократить потребление ресурсов и увеличить кпд?
Selenium Standalone Server только замедляет работу.

Comment: Вы уверены что какой-нибудь сайт throttle не включил из-за частых обращений? Где узкое место память? CPU?  диск? network latency? bandwidth? Что логи показывают? Как  chrome запускаете headless? Заново для каждого теста создаёте webdriver.Chrome или chromedriver как сервис + .Remote? Сервисы (translate, sync, extensions, etc) выключены? Приведите минимальный но полный пример кода, который слишком медленно  работает (укажите время и нагруженность машины) — создайте искусственный если необходимо [mcve]. Насколько вы хотите его улучшить (укажите время). Приведите характеристики железа, версии ПО